# producer a JPA entity

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, cdi

I'm using glassfish 4 ( WELD-000900 2.0.0 ).

I'm starting a prototype, so some entities are dummy objects. I want to inject from a CDI Producer, and I want to have only one entity .

```
 @Named("pedidoCtrl")
    @SessionScoped
    public class PedidoController implements Serializable{


        @Inject @ConexionDB
        private EntityManager em;

        private @Inject Cliente cli;

       private void foo(){
                this.pedido = new Pedido();
                this.pedido.setCliente(cli);
                em.persist(pedido);
            }
        }
```

The entities "pedido" and "cliente" are in a relationship are "cascade.Persist" is setted.
I've tried a procutor like that

```
@Dependent
public class UtilController {

    @Produces @ApplicationScoped 
    public Cliente getCliente(){
        Cliente cli = new Cliente();
        cli.setCuit(20123423);
        cli.setNombre("Martin");
        cli.setMail("mdominguez@mail.com");
        return cli;
    }
}
```

And it doesnt't work (eclipse link says "is not a known entity type" .

So I've change it in that way

```
@Dependent
public class UtilController {
    private static final Cliente _CLI = new Cliente(); 

    static {
        _CLI.setCuit(20123423);
        _CLI.setNombre("Martin");
        _CLI.setMail("mdominguez@mail.com");
    }

    @Produces 
    public Cliente getCliente(){
        return UtilController._CLI;
    }
}
```

And now it's working.

Why? it's only because the scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When CDI tries to make bean (`Cliente`) to be an Application scoped it wraps it into a proxy class. And when you pass an instance of the proxy to EclipseLink it detects the proxy class which cannot be found in its mappings.

In general I do not like your solution, to have eclipse link entity passed through injection somewhere. But it is a different issue.